# How do I submit test results to Microsoft Test Managment Server via HTTP?

Tags: http, testing, tfs, mtm

My company uses Microsoft Test Management server to host its tests and results. For the manual tests this works fine a QA engineer runs the test and marks its status, I have been tasked with writing some automated tests and I need them to submit results to the server. I know there is a code api, but I want to do this from a non .Net test environment (I am going to use AutoIt) so I would like to submit results from an HTTP api, how can I do this? Where can I find some good examples? Or is there a better way, we are a very MS TFS shop so whatever I do needs to fit into that environment.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a UI automation framework and API called CodedUI that is fully integrated with Microsoft Test Manager.

You can:

1. Generate test automations from Action recordings of manual tests
2. Generate test automations in Visual Studio
3. Code test automations from scratch in VS

These automations can then be associated with a Test Case in MTM and pushed to test environments manually or via an API. I usually have new code built, deployed, and tested automatically using these techniques.

You can also plug other UI frameworks into this model.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, however that really is not an answer to my question. While good to know not useful in solving my current issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit Test Results from a non-windows environment then you should use the Cross-Platform API. As part of Team Explorer Everywhere you get both a command line and a Java based Object Model for manipulating TFS.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47727

I should note that the API for constructing test result submissions is quite complex as your tests in MTM are part of a hierarchy of Suits and Plans, and each Test Case can exist in more than one location. You will need to create a Test Run and populate it with the appropriate data.